# Why the extension dimension of $x^3-2$ equal to $6$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

I have seen couple questions related to this one, but after reading the answers I am still confused:

> Why is the extension dimension of $x^3 - 2$ equal to $6$? In other words, why are the basis $1,\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[3]4,ω,ω\sqrt[3]2,ω\sqrt[3]4$? What happens to $ω^2,ω^2\sqrt[3]2$ and $ω^2\sqrt[3]4$? Why are they not basis elements as well? If the extension dimension is equal to the order of $G$, then is there a one-to-one correspondence between the basis and the elements of $G$?

Comment: @Travis’s answer puts his finger on it: adjoining a (primitive) cube root of $1$ is not a cubic extension but a quadratic one.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** If $\omega$ is a nontrivial cube root of unity, then $\omega^3 - 1 = 0$ but $\omega - 1 \neq 0$. Thus,
$$0 = \frac{\omega^3 - 1}{\omega - 1} = \omega^2 + \omega + 1,$$
and rearranging gives $$\omega^2 = -\omega - 1.$$

Comment: Thank you for your hint and for editing my question! I'm totally a starter so I don't really know how to type a lot of math notations. I think you have answered my first question. My second question is whether there exists a correspondence relation between the basis and the element of the Galois group. Intuitionally I think there might be one since the trivial extension and extension of degree 2 are good examples. But I am not sure about extension of higher degrees.

Comment: @JoyYan You're welcome. An important theorem of Artin says that the answer to your second question is yes when the extension itself is *Galois*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension. In particular, this is true for the splitting field of any separable polynomial (over a field of characteristic $0$, or more generally over a perfect field, this is the same thing as having no repeated roots).